# Using the Id of td how to fing id of corresponding tr?

Tags: jquery

i have id of td and i want to get the id of parent tr? i have following code

```
 $(".isActive").click(function() {
   var checkBox_id = $(this).attr("id");          // id of checkbox inside td//
   var $this = $('#' + checkBox);
   var column_id = $this.parent().attr('id');     // id of td//
   var row_id =   ???                              // get id or tr using above td
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to follow a chain of IDs - jQuery can find the closest enclosing table row for you:

```
$(".isActive").click(function() {
   var row_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var column_id = $this.parent().parent().attr('id') //id of tr
```

Comment: Use closest() that it's better

Answer (score 0):

You could use this i think

```
var row_id =   $this.closest('tr').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways of doing it:

```
var row_id = $this.parent().parent().attr('id');
var row_id = $('#' + column_id).parent().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing a point here:

```
var checkBox_id = $(this).attr("id");
var $this = $('#' + checkBox);
```

The second line is is completly unnecessary. `$this` will refer to the same element as `$(this)`. You just can do:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

for the same effect.

If you need the id of the `td`and `tr` for the same thing, then you don't need it either.

```
var $td = $this.parent(); // Reference to td
var $tr = $td.parent(); // Reference to tr
```